# An Ember Model's Date Properties Become Null Between Route Code Running and Template Rendering

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm having trouble saving date properties on my models in my Ember app and getting them to stick. My model's edit page (`dataset.edit`) has a save action that should set the model's updatedAt property to the current time, save the model, and then transition to a page that displays the model's new properties (`dataset.index`). Logging code in the save action shows that the date values are set correctly at this point (though mysteriously the Ember inspector reports the date properties being empty even after `model.save()` is called).

When the app transitions to `dataset.index` to display the model's new properties to the user, the model has its dates set correctly in the route's `model` hook, but by the time the template gets rendered all of the model's date properties become null! Any attempt to get the date properties from the template or controller only sees null values... even though those same date properties were set correctly when the route's `model` hook ran. How is that possible?

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
DataGatherer.ApplicationSerializer = DS.LSSerializer.extend();
DataGatherer.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'DataGatherer'
});


App.Dataset = DS.Model.extend({

    // The time at which this model was last updated.
    updatedAt: DS.attr('date')
});


App.DatasetEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.modelFor('dataset');
    }
});

App.DatasetEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        save: function() {
            var self = this;

            var dataset = this.get('model');
            dataset.set('updatedAt', new Date());
            // DEBUG
            console.log("After setting Dataset.updatedAt:");
            console.log(dataset.get('updatedAt'));  // correctly prints the date
            }
            dataset.save().then(function() {
                // DEBUG
                console.log("After saving:");
                console.log(dataset.get('updatedAt'));  // correctly prints the date
                self.transitionToRoute('dataset.index', dataset);
            });
        }
});


App.DatasetRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('dataset', params.dataset_id);
    }
});


App.DatasetIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        // DEBUG
        var model = this.modelFor('dataset');
        console.log('After loading new route:');
        console.log(model.get('updatedAt'));  // correctly prints the date

        return this.modelFor('dataset');
    }
});


App.DatasetIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
     actions: {
        whatsTheDate: function() {
            // DEBUG
            console.log("Dataset.updatedAt:");
            console.log(this.get('model').get('updatedAt'));  // when invoked prints null!
         }
     }
});
```